# How to remove a character in a specific position in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

So, I am trying to add and remove characters from an array. I have an add_to_array function which works fine. It prints out exactly what it should. However, I can't seem to remove a character from the end of my array. My code at the attempt was:

```
void delete_array(char *q, char f)
{
  char *blah = q;
  while(*blah != '\0')
  {
    blah--;
  }
  *blah = f;
  blah--;
  *blah = '\0';
 }
```

My code for my add_to_array was exactly the same except it was blah++ and I thought removing a character would just be the opposite. It compiles but it prints "segmentation fault (core dumped)" as an output. Where am I going wrong? Thank you for any suggestions/help.

Comment: You are going backwards (`blah--`) and at some point you are simply moving `blah` out of bounds of your array (which causes the segmentation fault). What exactly where you trying to achieve? reach the end of the array? then you still have to move forwards (`blah++`)

Comment: `blah--` causes undefined behaviour the first time it is executed. I hope you are passing the pointer to the first character in `delete_array`.

Comment: Your title talks about  remove in a **specific** position. Your code does no such thing. Please clarify what you want the function to do and how you want to call it.`

Comment: @4386427 - Sorry, I should have framed it like this: If `q` is a pointer to the first character of the string which the OP wants to modify, then `blah--` is UB.

Comment: @4386427 A better of example of what I am trying to do is remove a specific location in an array. I was going to use delete_array to remove a word that I made with my add_array function. So my Add_array will print the word fish and I want to use delete_array(&(x[2])); to delete the 's'.

Comment: @CodeFreak - so why do you pass two arguments to the function? Do you consider `q` to be a string? If so, then don't talk about removing from an array! It is something completely different.

Comment: @4386427 The code I had was given by my professor for my add_function. The delete_array code(listed above) was also given. My add function did blah++ to add characters and worked. What is your suggestion on how to remove a character then? The characters were added in an array and not a string

Comment: @CodeFreak - I would like to help but I simply can't understand what you want the function to do. Your title mentions a "specific position" but your code more looks as if you want to remove a specific character. Further, it makes a lot of difference whether we talk about a string or an array. You keep saying "array" but I think you really mean "string". The answers given so far also assumes that you talk about "string". Maybe if you showed your add-function and showed how you call it, I can figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void delete_array(char *str, char ch){
//To remove the specified character from a string
    char *to, *from;

    for(to = from = str; *from != '\0'; ++from){
        if(*from != ch)
            *to++ = *from;
    }
    *to = '\0';
}
int main(void){
    char str[] = "application";

    delete_array(str, 'p');
    printf("%s\n", str);//alication
    return 0;
}
```

---

In the case of deletion of the character of the particular position you need to include the position in the parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void delete_array(char *str, size_t pos){
//Delete the character of the position pos.
    char *p;

    for(p = str + pos; *p = p[1] ; ++p)
        ;
}
int main(void){
    char str[] = "application";

    delete_array(str, 3);
    printf("%s\n", str);//appication
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code shows you how you can remove a character in a string.

```
void delete_array(char *q, char f)
{
  char *blah = q;
  char *temp;
  while(*blah != '\0')
  {
    if(*blah == f){
        while(*blah != '\0'){             
            temp = blah;            
            temp++;            
            *blah = *temp;            
            blah++;        
        }
        break;
    }    
    blah++;
  }
}
```